# Unable to start JBoss, Filenotfoundexception

Tags: web-applications, intellij-idea, jboss

Recently I found out none of my new projects are working correctly with JBoss anymore. I always get a FileNotFoundException at startup:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Java_Projects\expenses\target\expenses-1.0-SNAPSHOT (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

No wonder he can't find that directory, since I deleted the `expenses` project a long time ago, it was just a temporary project where I probably misconfigured JBoss.

This happens with any project I start up, always looking for this particular path.

I configured the artifact in IntelliJ to use this as an output directory `C:\Java_Projects\household-web\target\household-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`

However I have no idea where to configure this, I can not find the `expenses` word anywhere in the standalone.xml configuration file of JBoss and using the plugin from IntelliJ I am also not able to spot any errors there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas after I had no answers I just solved this by reinstalling JBoss, though I still have no idea what could have possibly caused this